# How to generate an adapted frame for arbitrary curve?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I was reading [a paper about Bishop frame](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319846#metadata_info_tab_contents) and try to calculate the Bishop frame for a cubic bezier curve. My plan to do so is to generate an arbitrary adapted frame $\left\{T, N_1, N_2 \right\}$ and then solve the ODE regarding the angle $\theta$ between the Bishop frame and the adapted frame. My problem is, how can I derive the **explicit** formula for the adapted frame? Note that the adapted frame must be at least 1 order differentiable.

[1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319846#metadata_info_tab_contents) proposed the method of applying Gram-Schmidt process to $T$ "and two parallel field", which seems not working because GS process requires **independent** vectors as input.

The problem can actually be stated in a more general way. Given one vector $T$, how can one generate an orthogonal base containing this vector in an **explicit** way? In $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can define an "up" vector $U$, normalize $F = U \times T$ to get the "front" vector, then $T \times F$ will be the "right" vector. However, this method has flaws: it will degenerate when $T$ happens to be parallel to $U$. As a result, you have to discuss this situation, making the formula not **explicit**. What I want is a formula that satisfy
$$f(T) \perp T $$
for every possible $T$.

Is that possible?

Also, if that is not possible, I would like to know if there is another way to deal with my original problem.

Comment: Here's one suggestion that works when the curve is $C^2$ (so that the tangent indicatrix is $C^1$). The image of the unit tangent vector field is a $C^1$ curve in the unit sphere and hence has measure zero. Pick any element $A$ of the unit sphere not in its image and then use Gram-Schmidt with $T$ and $A$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment. But I would like a "global" formula. I am actually trying to physically simulate a curve ([physics based simulation](https://www.physicsbasedanimation.com/)) and when the curve changes, I do not want to pick another pole.

Comment: @TedShifrin Your comment is very insightful, though. I though maybe I can use the fact that the tangent vector of the whole cubic bezier curve lies in the positive span of three vectors $P_3 - P_2, P_2 - P_1, P_1 - P_0$ and choose a pole from the negative span. This way the cost will not be high in each timestep.

Comment: I was about to amend my comment to say "piecewise $C^2$" since you're working with Bézier. But, yes, if your curves are well-enough controlled as you say, then finding a "pole" for them all should work fine.

Comment: I can’t access the paper you cited, so I don’t know what a “Bishop frame” is. But, what’s wrong with using the Frenet frame?

Comment: The tangent vectors are described by a Bézier curve of degree 2, which is a parabola. Pick a “pole” vector that does not lie in the plane of this parabola.

Comment: You might benefit from reading about “rotation minimizing frames”. Page 31 of this thesis has a long list of references on the topic: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08830.pdf#page27

Comment: @bubba Thanks for your reply. For starters, when the bezier curve becomes a straight line, Frenet curve won't apply. But more importantly, what I am doing is simulating an elastic rod that is almost impossible to twist. So I have to use a twist-free frame as the material frame of that rod, where Bishop frame comes into play(see [this paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/cg/pdfs/143-rods.pdf)).

Answer (score -1):

A partial answer to the problem:

According to [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27834/generate-a-set-of-orthogonal-vectors-to-a-given-vector/27843#27843?newreg=95addca59a4047fb82dcee8b470b0a08). The general problem of assigning an orthogonal base containing vector $v$ that is also continuously depend on $v$ is not possible in three dimensional space.

Suppose such function exists (and not trivial), then we have a non vanishing tangent vector field of $S^2$, which contradicts the [Hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)

A workaround can be found in the comments of the problem. Basicly, we don't need a general formula for every vector since the tangent mapping of the curve corresponds to only a small fraction of $S^2$, we can easily pick a vector that does not lie on the tangent mapping.

Comment: Yes, of course, there is no framing of the entire two-sphere, but I don't see why that is relevant in your problem, unless *all* the curves you want to consider will fill up the two-sphere with their tangent directions.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know, so this answer is only to the **general statement** of the problem.

Comment: Your answer links to several off-site sources, and refers to comments below your question, which are, by design, ephemeral and subject to deletion.  Please edit your answer so that it is as self-contained as possible.  You can refer to comments and outside sources, but please try to summarize as much as possible.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your advice. But I was wondering which part of my proof is unclear? I have already provided a proof of my general problem, which is, btw, very obvious once someone know hairy ball theorem. I did cite this theorem from wikipedia, but I may choose not to cite it because you will find out what that is once you know its name, do I need to remove this citation ?